# c# delete all files but not last one

Tags: c#, .net, file-handling

i am trying to delete all images in image directory except the last image loaded in picture box and using th following code to achive this but still getting **file in use exception**

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Images\\");

            foreach (FileInfo file in di.GetFiles())
            {
                if(file.FullName!=pictureBoxLoadImage.ImageLocation)
                file.Delete();
            }
```

Comment: did your if statement returns "false" for the last image ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, it skips the last file from the files and delete the remaining

```
  System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Images\\");
  var files = di.GetFiles();
  files.AsParallel().Reverse().Skip(1).ForAll((f) => f.Delete());
```

Comment: Why do you need a second call to Reverse?

Comment: @Steve not needed :)

Comment: You can do that without calling reverse function just user .Take(files.Length - 1)

Answer (score 0):

I think `ImageLocation` here returns the relative paths of your images, that will make your `if` statement returns `true` always even for the last image, to fix this you should convert the path returned by `ImageLocation` to the absolute path:

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Images\\");

foreach (FileInfo file in di.GetFiles())
{
   if(file.FullName!= Path.GetFullPath(pictureBoxLoadImage.ImageLocation))
      file.Delete();
}
```